# Implementing Permutation of Complex Numbers In TensorFlow

Tags: permutation, tensorflow

In this associative lstm paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.03032, they ask to permute a complex tensor.

They have provided their code here: https://github.com/mohammadpz/Associative_LSTM/blob/master/bricks.py#L79

I'm trying to replicate this in tensorflow. Here is what I have done:

```
# shape: C x F/2
# output = self.permutations: [num_copies x cell_size]
permutations = []
indices = numpy.arange(self._dim / 2) #[1 ,2 ,3 ...64]
for i in range(self._num_copies):
    numpy.random.shuffle(indices) #[4, 48, 32, ...64]
    permutations.append(numpy.concatenate(
        [indices,
         [ind + self._dim / 2 for ind in indices]]))
    #you're appending a row with two columns -- a permutation in the first column, and the same permutation + dim/2 for imaginary
# C x F (numpy)
self.permutations = tf.constant(numpy.vstack(permutations), dtype = tf.int32) #This is a permutation tensor that has the stored permutations
# output = self.permutations: [num_copies x cell_size]

def permute(complex_tensor): #complex tensor is [batch_size x cell_size]
 gather_tensor = tf.gather_nd(complex_tensor, self.permutations)
 return gather_tensor
```

Basically, my question is: How efficiently can this be done in TensorFlow? Is there anyway to keep the batch size dimension fixed of `complex tensor`?

Also, is `gather_nd` the best way to go about this? Or is it better to do a for loop and iterate over each row in `self.permutations` using `tf.gather`?

```
def permute(self, complex_tensor):
 inputs_permuted = []
 for i in range(self.permutations.get_shape()[0].value):
  inputs_permuted.append(
    tf.gather(complex_tensor, self.permutations[i]))
 return tf.concat(0, inputs_permuted)
```

I thought that `gather_nd` would be far more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out, the trick is to just use permute the original input tensor using tf transpose. This will allow you then to do a tf.gather on the entire matrix. Then you can tf concat the matrices together. Sorry if this wasted anyone's time.

Comment: As far as I could tell `perm=[ ] `is just permuting the dimension and not each row